# how to pick the employee id once corresponding to a variable which has multiple levels? In Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have 2 variables: Employee and Effect. The variable "Effect" has 4 levels 1,2,3,4, and 4 being the highest/major effect.
[Sample Excel image to explain better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA9nm.png)

And some employee has 2 effects tagged to them (image attached). I need to select the employee once based on the higher effect level value. such that it will be counted once not twice. can you please help me?

[Original Tableau image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5DOe.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum this formula:

```
INT([Effect] = {FIXED [Employee Id]:MAX([Effect])})
```

This should count one record for each employee

Comment: Thank you very much. I was brainstorming with this part"{FIXED [Employee Id]:MAX([Effect])})" but could not figure it out. You add the "INT(Effect)=" and everything is in place. Do you mind explaining the first part of the code?

Comment: Sure. This part returns a boolean:
    [Effect] = {FIXED [Employee Id]:MAX([Effect])}
Wrapping in INT converts this to a number for further aggregating. i.e. True becomes 1 and False becomes 0.